# Jquery toggleclass hover

Tags: jquery, hover, toggleclass

I got this sub menu on my link SLIDE, the thing is when i clicked to close the sub menu if i move the cursor somewhere else but the 'SLIDE' link it works fine, but if i close it and my cursor stay on the link the toggleclass of .hover is tigger, so i got a link 'active' and nothing to show.

http://jsfiddle.net/6GPtg/13/

How can i fix that, this is driving me crazy...
thanks

```
    $(".border").hover(function(){
        if($(this).next('.sous_menu').is(':visible')){
            $('.sous_menu').closest('.border').removeClass('border').addClass('border_active');

        }else{
            $(this).toggleClass('border_active border', 500);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".border").click(function (e) {
    $(".sous_menu").slideUp('fast');
    if ($(this).next('.sous_menu').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).next(".sous_menu").slideUp('fast');
        if(!$(this).hasClass('border_active'))
        $(this).toggleClass('border_active border', 500);
    } else {
        $(this).next(".sous_menu").slideDown('fast');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CuCaQ/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Preferably use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `hover`.

```
$(".border").on({
    "mouseenter": function(){
        if($(this).next('.sous_menu').is(':visible')){
            $('.sous_menu').closest('.border').removeClass('border').addClass('border_active');
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('border_active', 500);
        }
    },
    "mouseleave": function(){
        if($(this).next('.sous_menu').is(':visible')){
            $('.sous_menu').closest('.border').removeClass('border').addClass('border_active');
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('border_active', 500);
        }
    }
});
```

There, done! [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GPtg/32/)

You had this `$(this).toggleClass('border_active border', 500);` which also toggled the `border` class

Comment: I see, I do like so but now there's nothing happening... http://jsfiddle.net/6GPtg/17/

Comment: Yea Im trying myself too, I tend to have some typos in there